# How the representation of an affine variety changes from an affine space to another one?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let take the zero set of  $x^{2}-x $ in $\mathbb{A}_{\mathbb{R}}^1 $ then it's representation it well be just the points $0$ and $1$

But when we take the zero set in
$\mathbb{A}_{\mathbb{R}}^2$ then its representation it well be the two parallel vertical lines pass through 0 and 1 respectively as In the picture [image]

I ask why in
$\mathbb{A}_{\mathbb{R}}^2$ the representation is changed why it didn't stay just as two-point ?

*Edit* what is the difference between  $V(x^2-x)$ and $V(x^2-x, y)$ in $\mathbb{A}_{\mathbb{R}}^2$

Comment: There seems to be some confusion here. Remember that in each of the examples you have there are other "variables" than $x$. The set $V(x^2-x)$ "in \mathbb A^2$ could be seen as $V(x^2-x,y)$. Here it is just two points.

Comment: In the case of $\mathbb{A}^3$ am I right ?

Comment: But what is the difference between $V(x^2-x)$  and $V(x^2-x, y)$in $\mathbb{A}^2$?

Comment: @Abdallahchaibedrraa You can think of the second one as the projectin of the first one onto the $y=0$-plane.

Comment: What about in hiegher dimension ?

Comment: The point is that in $\mathbb{A}^2$, taking $V(x^2-x)$ only asks for $x^2-x = 0$. So the points $(0,y)$ and $(1,y)$ for any $y$ satisfies the equation, because $y$ doesn't show up in the equation. On the other hand, if you take $V(x^2-x,y)$ then you're also asking for $y=0$ and so the only points that work are $(0,0)$ and $(1,0)$.

Comment: @Ashwin lyenger thank you very much your answer help me so much , so if we work in $\mathbb{A}^3 $ and we take $V(x^2-x)$ we get $(0,y,z)$ and $(1,y,z)$ ,if We choose $V(x^2-x,y)$ we get $(0,0,z)$ and $(0.1,z)$ if we take $ V(x^2-x,y,z)$ we get two points (0,0,1) and (0,1,0) ,am i right?

Comment: Yep, exactly right! Except that i think you have a small typo, which is that if you look at $V(x^2-x,y)$ in $\mathbb{A}^3$ the solutions are $(0,0,z)$ and $(1,0,z)$ and if you look at $V(x^2-x,y,z)$ you get $(0,0,0)$ and $(1,0,0)$

Comment: Yes i understand i just switched the position of 1 ,any way thank you again .

Comment: Yes i understand i just switched the position of 1 ,any way thank you again .